# How to combine a dict to a json file as an object with same index in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

The question may be confusing I know however, I don't know how to ask this properly.

Let me explain the issue. I have a json file like this:

```json
{
    "0": "MyItem",
    "1": "AnotherItem"
}
```

Then I am generating a dictionary with the same context above. Like this.

```json
{
    "UniqueId": "52355",
    "AnotherUniqueId": "234235"

}
```

They have same length. What I want to do is I want to parse this dictionary to this json file at the same index as an object like:

```json
{
    {"0": "MyItem", "UniqueId": "52355"}
    {"1": "AnotherItem", "AnotherUniqueId": "234235"}

}
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: What was the difficulty when you tried to do this?

Comment: I am kinda asking how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

it takes item of each dict and combines them with `{ **dict1, **dict2 }`
then stores each dict as key-value pairs of final dicts.

```
n = {
    "0": "MyItem",
    "1": "AnotherItem"
}

m = {
    "UniqueId": "52355",
    "AnotherUniqueId": "234235"
}

c = {}
for i, keys in enumerate(zip(n, m)):
    a, b = keys
    c[i] = { **{a:n[a]} , **{b:m[b]} }

print(c)
```

output :

```
{
 0: {'0': 'MyItem', 'UniqueId': '52355'},
 1: {'1': 'AnotherItem', 'AnotherUniqueId': '234235'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionaries in the final dictionary need to be accompanied by some sort of key since a dictionary is a key-value pair, it wouldn't make sense to not have a key for a value. The output you should go after is this for example

```
{
    0: {"0": "MyItem", "UniqueId": "52355"},
    1: {"1": "AnotherItem", "AnotherUniqueId": "234235"}

}
```

Here's my solution

```py
b = {
    "UniqueId": "52355",
    "AnotherUniqueId": "234235"
}
a = {
    "0": "MyItem",
    "1": "AnotherItem"
}
# Assuming a and b are of the same length

c = {} # will contain the final dictionaries
index = 0
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    temp = {} 
    temp[i]=a[i]
    temp[j]=b[j]
    c[index] = temp
    index+=1
print(c)
```